# Count the number of adjacent boxes

Tags: c++, algorithm, simulation, rectangles

Suppose I have a set of (X,Y) coordinates of 1000 boxes.

```
         (    x1,    y1)    (    x2,    y2)      Area

         (0.0000,0.0000)    (0.3412,0.4175)    0.1424
         (0.7445,0.0000)    (1.0000,0.6553)    0.1674
         (0.7445,0.6553)    (1.0000,1.0000)    0.0881
         (0.0000,0.6553)    (0.7445,1.0000)    0.2566
         (0.3412,0.0000)    (0.7445,0.4175)    0.1684
         (0.3412,0.4175)    (0.7445,0.6553)    0.0959
         (0.0000,0.4175)    (0.3412,0.6553)    0.0812 ....etc
```

I would like to calculate the number of adjacent boxes for each of them using c/c++ . How can I do it?

*Example*

[image]

In this picture, the total number of adjacent boxes for box-7 is six, for box-3 is three. How can I count them using c++?

**Edited and Updated with new values**

Let's try it for 16 values-

```
1   0.0000   0.0000      0.8147   0.1355  
2   0.8147   0.0000      1.0000   0.1355  
3   0.8147   0.1355      0.9058   0.8350  
4   0.0000   0.1355      0.1270   0.9689  
5   0.9058   0.1355      0.9134   0.2210  
6   0.9058   0.8350      1.0000   1.0000  
7   0.8147   0.8350      0.9058   1.0000  
8   0.1270   0.1355      0.6324   0.3082  
9   0.1270   0.9689      0.8147   1.0000  
10   0.0000   0.9689     0.1270   1.0000 
11   0.9134   0.1355     1.0000   0.2210 
12   0.9134   0.2210     1.0000   0.8350 
13   0.9058   0.2210     0.9134   0.8350 
14   0.6324   0.1355     0.8147   0.3082 
15   0.6324   0.3082     0.8147   0.9689 
16   0.1270   0.3082     0.6324   0.9689
```

For these values the unit square become like this picture-

[image]

And the updated code-

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    class Rect {
    public:
      double x1, x2, y1, y2; // assuming x1 <= x2 and y1 <= y2

      Rect(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) {
        if (X1 < X2) {
          x1 = X1; x2 = X2;
        } else {
          x2 = X1; x1 = X2;
        }
        if (Y1 < Y2) {
          y1 = Y1; y2 = Y2;
        } else {
          y2 = Y1; y1 = Y2;
        }
      }

      bool isAdjacent(Rect rect) {

    //for x-axis
           if (x1 == rect.x2 || x2 == rect.x1) {     
    // use only < when comparing y1 and rect.y2 avoids sharing only a corner
                  if (y1 >= rect.y1 && y1 < rect.y2) {
                    return true;
                  }
                  if (y2 > rect.y1 && y2 <= rect.y2) {
                    return true;
                  }
    }              
    // for y-axis    

                if (y1 == rect.y2 || y2 == rect.y1) {
                if (x1 >= rect.x1 && x1 < rect.x2) {
                    return true;
                  }
                  if (x2 > rect.x1 && x2 <= rect.x2) {
                    return true;
                  }
                 }

                return false;  

   }
    };

int main() {

      vector<Rect> rects;     

      rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.0000, 0.8147,0.1355));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.0000, 1.0000,0.1355));

      rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.1355, 0.9058,0.8350));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.1355, 0.1270,0.9689 ));

      rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.1355, 0.9134,0.2210));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.8350, 1.0000,1.0000));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.8350, 0.9058,1.0000));



      rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.1355, 0.6324,0.3082));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.9689, 0.8147,1.0000));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.9689, 0.1270,1.0000));

      rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.1355, 1.0000,0.2210));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.2210, 1.0000,0.8350));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.2210, 0.9134,0.8350));


      rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.1355, 0.8147,0.3082));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.3082, 0.8147,0.9689));
      rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.3082, 0.6324,0.9689));

int adj_count = 0;
      int b;
      cin>>b;

        for (int x = 0; x < rects.size(); ++x) {


        if (rects[b].isAdjacent(rects[x])) {


    if (x==b) {
      continue; //this is our rectangle , so do not count it.
    }


          adj_count++;
        cout << "rect["<<(b+1)<<"] is adjacent with rect["<<(x+1)<<"]"<<endl;


    }
        }
        cout<<"adjacent count of rect["<<(b+1)<<"] is = "<<adj_count<<endl;


      return 0;
    }
```

**Problem**

Now for rectangle#1 it shows-

```
rect[1] is adjacent with rect[2]
rect[1] is adjacent with rect[4]
rect[1] is adjacent with rect[14]
adjacent count of rect[1] is = 3
```

It misses the rectangle#8 and 9 & 10 !! (Please check the new picture)

And for rectangle#2 it shows-

```
rect[2] is adjacent with rect[1]
rect[2] is adjacent with rect[3]
rect[2] is adjacent with rect[11]
adjacent count of rect[2] is = 3
```

It misses the rectangle#5 and 7 & 6 !!! (Please check the new picture)

How can I fix it?

Comment: You will have much better responses if you post code and a much more specific question.  Questions like this usually get downvoted and/or ignored.

Comment: @JakeSellers I am pretty active under the algorithm tag, this question seems rather okay in that tag's world. But of course, your advice is generally good.

Comment: Uhh ... you're comparing with the rect **itself** .... `if( rect[b].x1 == rect[b].x2 || rect[b].x2 ==rect[b].x1 ){`, it's always the `[b]` index ...

Comment: @aries0152: hey, sorry for my late update.  I have updated my answer (esp. isAdjacent())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A naive solution requires O(N^2) where N is the number of rectangle, here is how to do it faster.

Two rectangles are adjacent only if they have one coordinate in common (note that the reverse is not correct).  Therefore you can count the number of adjacent boxes faster by first partitioning your input rectangles using two hashes, one based on the x location of the rectangle, and the other based on the y location.  As a result, one rectangle will fit into four different hash buckets based on its x1, y1, x2, and y2.

---

***Example***

For example, rect `(0.0000,0.0000)    (0.3412,0.4175)` will be hashed into `bucketX(0.000)`, `bucketX(0.3412)`, `bucketY(0.0000)`, and `bucketY(0.4175)`.

From the input in the OP, bucketX(0.000) and bucketX(1.000) will have the following rectangles:

```
bucketX(0.0000):
   (0.0000,0.0000)    (0.3412,0.4175)
   (0.0000,0.4175)    (0.3412,0.6553)
   (0.0000,0.6553)    (0.7445,1.0000)
   (0.0000,0.4175)    (0.3412,0.6553)

bucketX(1.0000):
   (0.7445,0.0000)    (1.0000,0.6553)
   (0.7445,0.6553)    (1.0000,1.0000)
```

---

***Time Complexity***

The hashing step only requires O(N) computation time where N is the number of rectangles, and the resulting check requires O(m^2) where m is the size of the largest bucket which in most cases is much smaller than N.

---

***Checking adjacency within each hashed bucket***

Then, for all rectangles within the same hash bucket.  Check whether two rectangles are adjacent by determining whether they either have same x value and overlapped value in y or vice versa.

The following is an example of checking whether two rectangles are adjacent:

```
class Rect {
public:
  double x1, x2, y1, y2; // assuming x1 <= x2 and y1 <= y2

  ...

  bool isAdjacent(Rect rect) {
    if (x1 == rect.x1 || x1 == rect.x2 ||
        x2 == rect.x1 || x2 == rect.x2) {
      // use only < when comparing y1 and rect.y2 avoids sharing only a corner
      if (y1 >= rect.y1 && y1 < rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (y2 > rect.y1 && y2 <= rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y1 >= y1 && rect.y1 < y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y2 > y1 && rect.y2 <= y2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (y1 == rect.y1 || y1 == rect.y2 ||
        y2 == rect.y1 || y2 == rect.y2) {
      if (x1 >= rect.x1 && x1 < rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (x2 > rect.x1 && x2 <= rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x1 >= x1 && rect.x1 < x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x2 > x1 && rect.x2 <= x2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

***A Runnable Example***

Here provide a sample code for the adjacency check:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

class Rect {
public:
  double x1, x2, y1, y2; // assuming x1 <= x2 and y1 <= y2

  Rect(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) {
    if (X1 < X2) {
      x1 = X1; x2 = X2;
    } else {
      x2 = X1; x1 = X2;
    }
    if (Y1 < Y2) {
      y1 = Y1; y2 = Y2;
    } else {
      y2 = Y1; y1 = Y2;
    }
  }

  double area() {
    return (x2 - x1) * (y2 - y1);
  }

  bool isAdjacent(Rect rect) {
    if (x1 == rect.x1 || x1 == rect.x2 ||
        x2 == rect.x1 || x2 == rect.x2) {
      // use only < when comparing y1 and rect.y2 avoids sharing only a corner
      if (y1 >= rect.y1 && y1 < rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (y2 > rect.y1 && y2 <= rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y1 >= y1 && rect.y1 < y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y2 > y1 && rect.y2 <= y2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (y1 == rect.y1 || y1 == rect.y2 ||
        y2 == rect.y1 || y2 == rect.y2) {
      if (x1 >= rect.x1 && x1 < rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (x2 > rect.x1 && x2 <= rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x1 >= x1 && rect.x1 < x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x2 > x1 && rect.x2 <= x2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};

int main() {

  std::vector<Rect> rects;

  rects.push_back(Rect(9999, 9999, 9999, 9999));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.0000, 0.8147,0.1355));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.0000, 1.0000,0.1355));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.1355, 0.9058,0.8350));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.1355, 0.1270,0.9689));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.1355, 0.9134,0.2210));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.8350, 1.0000,1.0000));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.8350, 0.9058,1.0000));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.1355, 0.6324,0.3082));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.9689, 0.8147,1.0000));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.9689, 0.1270,1.0000));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.1355, 1.0000,0.2210));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.2210, 1.0000,0.8350));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.2210, 0.9134,0.8350));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.1355, 0.8147,0.3082));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.3082, 0.8147,0.9689));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.3082, 0.6324,0.9689));


  int adj_count = 0;
  int y = 1;
  for (int x = 0; x < rects.size(); ++x) {
    if (x == y) continue;
    if (rects[y].isAdjacent(rects[x])) {
      printf("rect[%d] is adjacent with rect[%d]\n", y, x);
    }
  }
  y = 2;
  for (int x = 0; x < rects.size(); ++x) {
    if (x == y) continue;
    if (rects[y].isAdjacent(rects[x])) {
      printf("rect[%d] is adjacent with rect[%d]\n", y, x);
    }
  }
}
```

and the output is:

```
rect[1] is adjacent with rect[2]
rect[1] is adjacent with rect[4]
rect[1] is adjacent with rect[8]
rect[1] is adjacent with rect[14]
rect[2] is adjacent with rect[1]
rect[2] is adjacent with rect[3]
rect[2] is adjacent with rect[5]
rect[2] is adjacent with rect[11]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using arrays to store the coordinates. So I was trying to use your *if..else* section for counting the rectangles. But it **returns only '0'**. :( I have edited my question and add my code snippet. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @aries0152: do you ensure the property that x1 <= x2 and y1 <= y2?

Comment: Yes,(x1,y1) are coordinates of lower left corner and (x2,y2) are the coordinates of upper right corner. So x1 < x2 & y1 < y2. I have edited my question again added an image. Please check.

Comment: @aries0512: I have included a minimum runnable code in my answer.

Comment: Suppose in the first picture of my question I want to consider the box#5 & box#6 are adjacent to box#4. Similarly the box#1 & box#5 are adjacent to box#2. i.e if I want to consider the top most boxes as adjacent to bottom and extreme right boxes are adjacent to left boxes how can I add them in the if-else condition?

Comment: @aries0152: you can simply convert the boundary value before the hashing and the if-then statement.  For example, you can add additional variable called x3 and y3 for each box, where let x3 = x2 if x2 != X_MAX_BOUNDARY (i.e. 1.000 in your case), otherwise let x3 = X_MIN_BOUNDARY (i.e., 0.000 in your case).  Do the samse thing in y3 and y2.  And use x1 x3 and y1 y3 in the hashing and if-statement part.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're interested in box B for which the (x0, y0, x1, y1) coordinates are:
(B.x0, B.y0, B.x1, B.y1)

Then with:

```
ax0 = min(x0,x1);
ax1 = max(x0,x1);
ay0 = min(y0,y1);
ay1 = max(y0,y1);
bx0 = min(B.x0,B.x1);
bx1 = max(B.x0,B.x1);
by0 = min(B.y0,B.y1);
by1 = max(B.y0,B.y1);
```

you go through the whole list of boxes (with a for loop) and you select the ones for which:

```
(((ay0 <= by1 && ay1 >= by0) && (ax1 == bx0 || ax0 == bx1) || // touch on x axis
 ((ax0 <= bx1 && ax1 >= bx0) && (ay1 == by0 || ay0 == by1))   // touch on y axis
```

Comment: This is not correct, they might just sharing same x value or y value but not adjacent because of the other coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you describe boxes share corners, so if you computed all of the box corners then you could see which ones were touching

```
// O(n)
foreach box b {
   // compute b's other 2 corners and save them
}

// 16 * O(n^2) = O(n^2) 
foreach box b {
   foreach box other {
      // match if any of b's corners match any of others points
   }
}
```

There is probably a much more efficient/elegant solution, this one is somewhat naive.

Comment: But if two rectangles share an edge without sharing any corners, this would be wrong?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei hmmm, I see what you mean. Like 6 & 2 from above ?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei Wait the bottom of 6 and bottom of 2 are still shared.

Comment: 2 & 6 seems to be sharing a corner, but if one of those is moved vertically they will not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you explain the movement ?

Comment: Imagine 2 is just a bit taller - not 100 percent sure, but that should prevent the rectangles from sharing a corner in that picture.

Comment: Using a hash to first partition the rectangles based on their locations would run faster than O(N^2)